# Exclude tag from post in many to many queries

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgres I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE post (id SERIAL, body TEXT);
CREATE TABLE tag (id SERIAL, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE post_tag (post_id INT, tag_id INT);

INSERT INTO post(body) values('post 1');
INSERT INTO post(body) values('post 2');
INSERT INTO tag(name) values('a');
INSERT INTO tag(name) values('b');
INSERT INTO post_tag values(1, 1);
INSERT INTO post_tag values(1, 2);
INSERT INTO post_tag values(2, 1);
```

Thus `post 1` has tags `a, b` and `post 2` has `a` as a tag.

**The question:** How to select all posts that don't have the tag `b`, meaning it should select only the `post 2`.

This query here is not good because it will select both posts given that `post 1` has 2 tags `a` & `b`:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post
JOIN post_tag ON post_tag.post_id = post.id
JOIN tag ON tag.id = post_tag.tag_id
WHERE tag.name != 'b';
```

This query below works, but is wrong because if there is a tag `aaaaaaab` then it will match it too:

```
SELECT post.id, post.body, string_agg(tag1.name, ', ')
FROM post
JOIN post_tag ON post_tag.post_id = post.id
JOIN tag ON tag.id = post_tag.tag_id
GROUP BY post.id, post.body
HAVING string_agg(tag.name, ', ') not like '%b, %';
```

I'm looking for a 'correct' and efficient approach to this.

**EDIT:** The query should also match posts that don't have any tags at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select posts with aggregated tags using the query:

```
select p.id, p.body, array_agg(t.name) tags
from post p
left join post_tag pt on pt.post_id = p.id
left join tag t on pt.tag_id = t.id
group by 1, 2;

 id |  body  | tags  
----+--------+-------
  1 | post 1 | {a,b}
  2 | post 2 | {a}
(2 rows)
```

With adequate modifications you can use the query to filter your data, e.g.

```
select p.id, p.body
from post p
left join post_tag pt on pt.post_id = p.id
left join tag t on pt.tag_id = t.id
group by 1, 2
having 'b' <> all(array_agg(t.name));
-- or to get also posts without tags:
-- having 'b' <> all(array_agg(t.name)) or array_agg(t.name) = '{null}';

 id |  body  
----+--------
  2 | post 2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks! How about posts that have no tags? Logically the should also be in the result. Sorry I haven't thought about this before.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, using subqueries is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM post
WHERE post.id IN (
  SELECT post_id
  FROM post_tag
  WHERE post_id != ALL (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM post_tag
    WHERE tag_id = (
      SELECT id
      FROM tag
      WHERE name = 'b'
      )
    )
  );
```

I'm not sure however how efficient this query is though, it's most definitely not the most readable.